# Conditional routing ReactJS according to date

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm building a website in ReactJS that allows users to fill out a form during the weekday but redirects to a closed page on the weekend. How would I conditionally route to a different page using react-router-dom? I'd also like it to not be local time, but according to, say, PST.
Thanks!

Comment: Create useEffect and check the time and day based on that …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your exact router setup, I can only guess, but here are some ideas:

1. The `useNavigate` hook:

   ```js
    import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    // check the current date, based on locale 
    useEffect(() => {
       // date-checking logic
       // if(weekday) { navigate('/weekday/specific/page'); }
       // if(weekend) { navigate('/weekend/specific/page'); }
       // else navigate('/wherever')
    }, []);
   ```

Note the use of `useEffect`, you want the logic to be checked upon mounting the component that decides whether the redirect should be performed or not.

2. `<Redirect />` component:

   ```
    import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
    // const weekday = (date checking logic)
    <Route exact path="/">
      {weekday ? <Redirect to="/weekday" /> : <Weekend />}
    </Route>
   ```